# Lag when parsing data from a website - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, lag

I wrote an app that parses data from a website into a tableview.

I also useMBProgressHUD to show feedback for the user when the parsing happens.

I call the loading method from the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    noConnectionAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"אין מידע להצגה"
                                               message:@"אין אפשרות להתחבר לאינטרנט."
                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"אישור"
                                     otherButtonTitles: nil];

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    HUD.labelText = @"טוען...";

    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadReports) 
                  onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

    BOOL hasConnection = [self hasInternetConnection];

    if (!hasConnection) {
       [noConnectionAlert show];
    } else {
       [self loadReports];
    }

}
```

I have a TabBar, so this loading happens in the first and second views.
The problem is that I notice a lag (when there is a slow internet connection) when the app is luanching and when I tap the second tab in the TabBar.

Is there another way so that the app will launch (or move to the next tab when tapped)  as fast as it can (and show the HUD as long as it takes it to load the data)?

edit:

here is loadReports:

```
- (void)loadReports {
NSURL *reportsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iba.org.il/moked/index.aspx?   classto=mokedTraffic"];
NSData *reportsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:reportsUrl];


NSString *encodedStringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:reportsHtmlData    encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsHebrew)];
NSLog(@"%@", encodedStringData);
NSData *reportsHtmlDataEncoded = [encodedStringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];

TFHpple *reportsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:reportsHtmlDataEncoded];
NSString *reportsXpathQueryString = @"//table//tr//td";
NSArray *reportsNodes = [reportsParser searchWithXPathQuery:reportsXpathQueryString];

for (int i = 0; i < reportsNodes.count - 1; i++) {
    TFHppleElement *nodeFirstChild = [(TFHppleElement *)reportsNodes[i] firstChild];
    if ([[nodeFirstChild tagName] isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", reportsNodes[i]);
        NSLog(@"%@", nodeFirstChild);
    }
}
NSMutableArray *newReports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

NSString *thisAttribute = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSDictionary *thisNode = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
for (TFHppleElement *element in reportsNodes){
    NSString *str = [[element firstChild] content];
    if (str != NULL) {
        TFHppleElement *firstChild = [element firstChild];
        NSArray *childStrong = [element childrenWithTagName:@"strong"];
        NSLog(@"%@", childStrong);
        NSString *mokedContent;
        for (TFHppleElement *strongElement in childStrong){
            NSLog(@"%@", [[[strongElement firstChild] firstChild] content]);
            mokedContent = [[[strongElement firstChild] firstChild] content];
        }

        thisNode = [element attributes];
        thisAttribute = (NSString *)[thisNode objectForKey:@"width"];
        if (thisAttribute == NULL) {
            NSArray *spanChildren = [element childrenWithTagName:@"span"];
            if (spanChildren.count > 0) {
                TFHppleElement *spanChild = [spanChildren objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *spanContent = [[spanChild firstChild] content];
                NSRange firstRange = [spanContent rangeOfString:@"\u00a0("];
                BOOL isFound = NO;
                if (firstRange.length > 0){
                    isFound = YES;
                    NSLog(@"String contains");
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"No found in string");
                }
                NSString *result = [spanContent stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:firstRange    withString:@""];
                NSRange secondRange = [result rangeOfString:@")\u00a0"];
                NSString *time = [result stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:secondRange withString:@""];
                NSLog(@"%@", time);

                ORDKolIsrael *kolIsraelTraffic = [[ORDKolIsrael alloc] init];
                [newReports addObject:kolIsraelTraffic];

                NSString *reportFinal = [firstChild content];
                kolIsraelTraffic.kolIsraelReport = reportFinal;

                kolIsraelTraffic.kolIsraelTime = time;
                NSLog(@"%@", kolIsraelTraffic.kolIsraelReport);
            }

        }
    }
}
_reports = newReports;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

edit(2):

I added a method to get the data asynchronously:

```
    - (void)getDataFromUrlString:(NSString *)string
    {
       //Set database address
    NSMutableString *databaseURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];

    //prepare NSURL with newly created string
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:databaseURL];

    //AsynchronousRequest to grab the data
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil){
             [self loadReports:data];
         }else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){

         }else if (error != nil && error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut){ //used this NSURLErrorTimedOut from foundation error responses

         }else if (error != nil){

         }
     }];
   }
```

I call this method from the viewDidLoad but the tableview is not getting the data (empty table) despite the fact that when I debugged the code I could see the desired data in the CellForRowAtIndexPath.
Any idea why?

Comment: The more important code here is in the `loadReports` method. What's that look like? Is it synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: It's on the main thread, I want the user to not be able to interact with the UI until it's loaded, hence the MBProgressHUD.

Comment: @oridahan still do your networking on a background thread to get rid of lag.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *reportsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:reportsUrl];
```

This line will pause your program until the request returns.  If you dont want the user to interact with the view, then setup an asynchronous request and show a view they can't interact with until the request completes.

So, you want an asynchronous connection. Read the docs on [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In short you will want to make a connection object:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection initWithRequest:request
                                                      delegate:self];
```

Then respond to some of the [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) such as:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Lastly, start it:

```
[connection start];
```

---

Or you can use a library like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) that makes all this setup much simpler.

Comment: @Sulthan It's not. `MBProgressHUD` doesn't appear to be in control of making the actual request. And that's what code needs to change.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks for your help. Can you see my edited question? I will try using the connection if my way is no good.

Comment: That's a different question. Trim down your posted code to just the part that deals with that and post a new question.